# Selenide+Spock, one class per page - navigating to a page seems to open a new window

Tags: internet-explorer, spock, selenide

I am new to both Spock and Selenide, so I apologize if it's smth obvious, I was not able to google an answer though.
I am trying to write a simple test for a Jenkins site (test machine only has access to local resources, so I cannot give a Google example, but should be about the same).

It opens the site, inputs a word in the search field, presses Enter, and then checks the search results for a match.

There are three classes:
1. JenkinsTest - where the test is written in Spock notation.
2. JenkinsPage - responsible for putting test in the search field and pressing Enter.
3. SearchResultsPage - responsible for checking the search results.

The problem is SearchResultsPage seems to open its own browser window instead of looking at the existing one. So when I look at $("body") from this class, I get "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.".
Is there a way to have a class per page, and still have them all hooked up to the same browser window? Currently JenkinsPage uses the same window that is originally opened, but SearchResultsPage opens a new browser window that is closed a second later.

JenkinsTest.groovy:

```
package sandbox-test;

import org.junit.Test;    
import static com.codeborne.selenide.CollectionCondition.sizeGreaterThan;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.text;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;    
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import spock.lang.*

class JenkinsTest extends spock.lang.Specification {    
    public void "Can search for assure"() {
        setup:
            open("http://local.hostname.com/jenkins/")          
        when:
            new JenkinsPage().searchFor("test")
            SearchResultsPage results = new SearchResultsPage()    
        then:
            results.getResults() == "testresults"               
    }
}
```

JenkinsPage.groovy:

```
package sandbox-test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.page;

class JenkinsPage {
  def searchFor(String text) {
    $(By.name("q")).val(text).pressEnter()
  }
}
```

SearchResultsPage.groovy:

```
package sandbox-test;

import com.codeborne.selenide.ElementsCollection;
import com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideElement;    
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$$;

class SearchResultsPage {
  public ElementsCollection getResults() {
    return $("body")
  }
  public SelenideElement getResult(int index) {
    return $("#main-panel li", index)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working in the end.

In JenkinsTest used this line for a "then" block:

```
results.getResult().getText().contains("assure-integration-ofm")
results.getResults().first().text == "assure-integration-ofm"
```

And rewrote SearchResultsPage.groovy as:

```
package sandbox-test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import com.codeborne.selenide.Condition;
import com.codeborne.selenide.ElementsCollection;
import com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide;
import com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideElement;

class SearchResultsPage {
  public ElementsCollection getResults() {
    ElementsCollection list = Selenide.$$(By.xpath("//ol/li"))
    return list
  }
  public SelenideElement getResult() {
    SelenideElement list = Selenide.$(By.xpath("//ol"))
    return list
  }
}
```

I still don't understand why didn't the original work, as I took it from the Selenide's examples and changed only slightly. But oh well.